# Displaying Plist data into UItableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist

I have a plist with Dictionary and numbers of strings per dictionary.show into the url below.and this list of items is in thousands in the plist.

I need to display these plist data into the UItableview

[image: eneter image]
.

How to do this?

My Code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"p.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

    valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

    self.mySections=[valueArray copy];
    NSLog(@"value array %@",self.mySections);

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.mySections count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *key = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"pass"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.mySections count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:1]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plist into UItableview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926898/plist-into-uitableview)

Comment: @NickBull that duplicate was already closed as a dupe of this one...

Answer (score 1):

You've run off the end of your array.

It's probably because you've hardcoded the number of rows for each section to be 5. Unless there really are 5 rows in each section, you should be returning a dynamic value here.

Comment: ya thanks...output is now coming...but not in proper form...plz check rowAtIndexPAth

Comment: How do I know how you expect your data to come out?

Comment: ok...Sections should display @"pass" and rows with in this should display all the Dictionary values including pass

Comment: search plist problem..help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985379/uisearchview-not-displaying-search-values