# Plist into UItableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5, plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying Plist data into UItableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912735/displaying-plist-data-into-uitableview)

I have a plist with Dictionary and numbers of strings per dictionary.show into the url below.and this list of items is in the plist.it gives me the output but...does not shows properly..i think    problem is in the `CellForRowatindexPath` and if NSLOG `valueArray` correct output comes

I need to display these plist data into the UItableview

[image: eneter image]
.

How to do this?

My Code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"p.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];

    valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

    self.mySections=[valueArray copy];
    NSLog(@"value array %@",self.mySections);

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.mySections count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *key = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"pass"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.mySections count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:1]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you think the problem is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set a breakpoint and step through the code and see where the wrong value is occurring. Or at least use NSLog and find out.

Comment: IT would be much more useful to see a printout of mySections array, rather than the plist. Also, what's wrong? You don't describe the problem --"does not show properly" isn't very informative.

Comment: have u set UITableViewDataSource properly

Comment: Also, do you really want to return self.mySections.count for both the number of sections and the number of rows?

Comment: @rdelmar if i nslog { value array (
        {
        pass = item;
        title = item;
    },
        {
        Protein = "";
        carbs = "";
        fats = "";
        pass = "";
        title = "";
    },
        {
        Protein = 7;
        carbs = 7;
        fats = 7;
        pass = sugar;
        title = 10;
    },
        {
        pass = hi;
        title = hii;
    }
)

Comment: nslog output is correct according to my data.. @rdelmar where i made the mistake

Comment: @CRDave yes I have already done this

Comment: can you please show what is wrong with the values? I guess you have different number of UI elements for collapseable cell and non-collapse able cell but the results screens got wrong after scrolling, right?

Comment: @WaqasRaja tableview is not coming correctly with input..section heading is correct...data within this is not

Comment: I think rdelmar is pointing to some valid issue correct numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: What is allKeys? Where do you define that?

Comment: hey sorry sorry...that I have edited the code ...but if i comment that part ...textlabel.text is also not correct

Comment: Well, I got your array and pasted in your code -- the table view is a mess. How to fix it? I can't tell unless you tell us what it's supposed to look like. It's such a mess I can't tell what you want.

Comment: ok forget my above plist...but it would be in same order Dictionaries in Array..NOw If want @"pass " should come in the section header and ...within section all vales should come

Comment: @rdelmar now is it easy to understand

Comment: No, it's not easy to understand -- what I get when I run is section titles: "item", "","sugar","hi". In each section I get the same thing: "item" , "", "10", "hi". What do you want in the sections?

Comment: like protein,carbs,fats,title should come in text label...and their respective values in the detailTextLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think this is what you want:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.mySections count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *key = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"pass"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section ] allKeys] count] ;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [dict valueForKey:[dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: man [[self.mySections[section],dict.allKeys[indexPath.row]; gives me some error-> `subscript require size of interface "NSARRAY" which is not constant in non-fragile ABI`...whats this??

Comment: [[self.mySections[section],dict.allKeys[indexPath.row] What is this? I don't have a line like that in my code. I tested this code, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: -> `return [[self.mySections[section] allKeys] count];` gives me error ->`subscript require size of interface "NSARRAY" which is not constant in non-fragile ABI`

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = `dict.allKeys`[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [dict valueForKey:`dict.allKeys`[indexPath.row]]; ..here also same error

Comment: @Christien, Maybe you're using an old Xcode (or compiler) that doesn't understand the new objective-c syntax for arrays and dictionaries. I've edited my code to do it the old way. try that instead.

Comment: ya thanksman...now it works..i was using...xcode 4.2..that was the reason..

Comment: @Christien, One problem with my method, that I don't think is easy to fix, is that the rows will also show a title for "pass" and a subtitle for its value. Because of the way your data is structured, that will be hard to parse out.

Comment: ya right..but no problem man!! you have done much..I will have hide it somehow.. and the output of rows comes in alphabetical order like firstly carbs,title then.... (abcd order) is there any way that it comes with random order or according to the plist

Comment: @Christien, Yes, you can alphabetize the dict.allKeys array to get them in order. That would be a way to hide the "pass" key/value pair as well, if you could change its name to something that would come last in the list like "zpass".

Comment: no Iam asking...already its coming in alphabetize order..is it possible like firstly protein then carbs then something else,...non alphabetize order

Comment: @Christien, I'm sure there must be a way, but I can't think of it now -- I'm tired and it's time for sleep.

Comment: ohh!! u r in U.s its must be night over there.. :) ..gudnyt and thanks a lot

Comment: search plist problem..help needed ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985379/uisearchview-not-displaying-search-values

Answer (score 1):

here properly set the `numberOfRowsInSection`  method with correct number of rows..

also here use `row` instead of `section`.. and also set `objectForKey` with string value ..

**UPDATE**

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"protein,carbs,fats,title";
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@",[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"protein"],[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"carbs"],[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"fats"],[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: not coming the correct output

Comment: @Christien what you get output in allKeys??

Comment: if i nslog { value array ( { pass = item; title = item; }, { Protein = ""; carbs = ""; fats = ""; pass = ""; title = ""; }, { Protein = 7; carbs = 7; fats = 7; pass = sugar; title = 10; }, { pass = hi; title = hii; } ) ....its correct one

Comment: i think you get title correct but not detail lable, right???

Comment: use valueForKey insted of objectFor key IF my.sections is NSMutableArray  try this [self.mySections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"pass"];

Comment: @Christien use pass key name like cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"pass"]; try it if you get output then post comment

Comment: yaI have don't this...but it will return only pass value ..

Comment: what you want exactly here you can get value with its key name dude... what you want in detail lable??

Comment: firstly text label is not coming correctly and  it would be in same order Dictionaries in Array..NOw If want @"pass " should come in the section header and ...within section all vales should come

Comment: not understand dude...?? :( i think you want to display all values of the arraydata with current indexRow??

Comment: ya it will come in the same row,,ryt...I want each row with respective key and value

Comment: @Christien here you have a this all values in one index of mysection array so here you need another array which store tha array with perticular key name .. instead pf it if you set this all values with this 4 lables in one cell then its very easy.. you understand dude??

Comment: ya thanks for the effort man!! but redelmar's answer(above answer) was the actually one..which i wanted ...thanks for your effort

Comment: yes tell me which about you want to know??

Comment: I have to track gps movement and calculate the miles covered..I am working first time on maps....I have one sample code which works fine but I am unable to implement in my code....can i have your mail id..to give you

Comment: ya dude.. paras.joshi3@gmail.com and i am not more able to on gmail dude bcoz here not allowed some sites like chating so...

Comment: https://github.com/benjdezi/TrackMe  ..ok then try this code

Comment: actually it want all the things of this project in mine one...but in this m not able changes in the appdelegate,so that firstviewcontroller come with all into one part

Comment: oh ok ok just try to understand whole flow of the code and also implement this whole code like array and method one by one and if possible then refer the tutorial about it dude.. i'll also help you when i am online dude... send mail with your problems.. :)]

Comment: ya tht is the problem ..i tried all appdelegate methods defined in the firstViewcontroller to implement in my code but Xcode crashes every time

Comment: hi..how can i start my app with a image...only image..waits for2-3 seconds than app loads

Comment: see my blog with this link and follow it dude.. http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/splashview-in-iphone.html

Comment: http://rghost.net/42400084 hey if it is possible check code..for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987238/plist-search-of-tableview