# Plist Search of Tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist, uisearchbar

I have `Plist` which is been populated on the tableview with expanded sections ..now i want to search the table..below in images you can see what is happening when I search anything.
.
just because I am searching it but need some changes in the cellforrowatindexpath for search results....

please check the code and let me know what to do for searching plist..
what should be changes for the `cellforrowatindexpath` and `noofrowsinsection` for search from plist

.

[image: first]
[image: sec]
.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{


return [self.mySections count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 NSInteger rows = 0;


if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section] || !(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) )
{
    if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section] )
    {

        NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *dataInSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];

        return [dataInSection count];


    }
    return 1;
 } else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

     rows = [self.searchResults count];
    return rows;
}

    return 1;


}

 -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section {
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

  //some changes required  to display plst
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

// Configure the cell...



if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else {

NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];



NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];

NSDictionary *dataForSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *array=dataForSection.allKeys;

cell.textLabel.text = [[dataForSection allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];    
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[dataForSection valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
{
    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
        BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
        NSInteger rows;


        NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        if (currentlyExpanded)
        {
            rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

        }
        else
        {
            [expandedSections addIndex:section];
            rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        }


        for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
        {
            NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i 
                                                           inSection:section];
            [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
        }

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (currentlyExpanded)
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

        }
        else
        {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray 
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            cell.accessoryView =  [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];

        }
    }
}
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText 
                         scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

self.searchResults = [self.mySections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
UISearchBar * searchBar = [controller searchBar];
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
UISearchBar * searchBar = [controller searchBar];
[self filterContentForSearchText:[searchBar text] scope:[[searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search results you are using in numberOfRows should be used for numberOfSections
Since you are filtering for section title and not rows.